# How do I repeat the first table row on every page using longtable inside of tcolorbox?

Tags: longtable, tcolorbox

I'm using the `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` but the first row is not repeated for some reason.
Here's a piece of my code, I'll appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\cellcolor[gray]{0.95}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%%
  breakable, 
  ]
\begin{longtable}{b{0.35cm}|b{2cm}||c|c|}
C. & HEADER    & {CSF1} & {CSF2}      \\\hline\hline\endfirsthead
C. & HEADER    & {CSF1} & {CSF2}      \\\hline\hline\endhead
P1 & Vyroba    & OK     & OK          \\\hline
P2 & Nakup     &        & OK          \\\hline
P3 & Prodej    & OK     & OK          \\\hline
P4 & Logistika &        &             \\\hline
P5 & Sklad     & OK     & OK          \\\hline
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
P6 & Inventura & OK     & OK          \\
% the table continues
\end{longtable}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I correct your MWE that now works and show your problem. As I see, you use ``tcolorbox`` just to have table head in shape with rounded upper corners. If you sacrifice this, you can obtain desired shadowing with ``\rowcolor{<desired color>} ...``.

Comment: Could this be related to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194723/colorbox-not-working-with-longtable)?

Comment: @nickie That doesn't solve this particular problem.

Comment: I've been digging through the code for `longtable`.  The header is stored in a box `\LT@head`.  But the boxing and unboxing of this relies upon register `\z@`.  I suppose that something might be happening between `tcolorbox` managing the page break and `longtable` trying to do the same that's interrupting each other.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, I guess I have no choice but to abandon the pretty tcolorbox table (I don't really need rounded corners, but I used `\caption` in the title as a part of the table which was handy) - do you think I can still use the `\definecolor{tablerow1}{}{}` to define alternating colours of rows in a simple `longtable`?

Comment: @A.Ellett Thanks, do you think it could be fixed using `frame code` definitions for each section of the broken `tcolorbox`? I found these in the manual for `tcolorbox` on p.201 but I haven't tried them. Or is it easier to use Zarko's solution?

Comment: @EliskaVlckova The content of a breakable `tcolorbox` is a huge `\vbox` which is broken using `\vsplit`. Therefore, the embedded `longtable` is set like on a huge single page and cannot repeat the header. So, unfortunately, there is no easy solution.

Comment: Could longtable be made aware of the `\vsplit` or is it _too late_ at this point of the typesetting procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't solution with tcolorbox, but as I mentioned in my comment similar look you can obtain (without rounded table top corners) with following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=15cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries}

    \usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*\OK{$\checkmark$}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}b}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b}

    \begin{document}
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{gray!5}
\begin{longtable}{|R{\dimexpr 0.055\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
                   R{\dimexpr 0.521\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}||
                  *{10}{C{\dimexpr 0.04\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\large\textbf{Tabulka procesů}}  \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
Č. & Proces & \rot{CSF1} & \rot{CSF2} & \rot{CSF3} & \rot{CSF4} & \rot{CSF5} & \rot{CSF6} & \rot{Suma} & \rot{Kvalita} & \rot{Význam IT} & \rot{Technická kvalita~}\\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
Č. & Proces & \rot{CSF1} & \rot{CSF2} & \rot{CSF3} & \rot{CSF4} & \rot{CSF5} & \rot{CSF6} & \rot{Suma} & \rot{Kvalita} & \rot{Význam IT} & \rot{Technická kvalita~}  \\
\hline\hline
\endhead
% telo tabele
P1 & Výroba                     & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & \OK   &       & 3 & B & A & B  \\ \hline
P2 & Nákup                      &       & \OK   &       &       & \OK   & \OK   & 3 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P3 & Prodej                     & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   &       & 5 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P4 & Logistika                  &       &       & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & 2 & B & B & C  \\ \hline
P5 & Sklad                      & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & \OK   & \OK   & 4 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P6 & Inventura                  & \OK   & \OK   &       &       &       & \OK   & 3 & B & B & B  \\  \hline

P1 & Výroba                     & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & \OK   &       & 3 & B & A & B  \\ \hline
P2 & Nákup                      &       & \OK   &       &       & \OK   & \OK   & 3 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P3 & Prodej                     & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   &       & 5 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P4 & Logistika                  &       &       & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & 2 & B & B & C  \\ \hline
P5 & Sklad                      & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & \OK   & \OK   & 4 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P6 & Inventura                  & \OK   & \OK   &       &       &       & \OK   & 3 & B & B & B  \\  \hline

% the table continuing on the next page

P1 & Výroba                     & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & \OK   &       & 3 & B & A & B  \\ \hline
P2 & Nákup                      &       & \OK   &       &       & \OK   & \OK   & 3 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P3 & Prodej                     & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   & \OK   &       & 5 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P4 & Logistika                  &       &       & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & 2 & B & B & C  \\ \hline
P5 & Sklad                      & \OK   & \OK   &       &       & \OK   & \OK   & 4 & B & B & B  \\ \hline
P6 & Inventura                  & \OK   & \OK   &       &       &       & \OK   & 3 & B & B & B  \\  \hline
\end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

It is based on your first MWE. I omit all not necessary packages and shortcuts, which disturb table lookout and was necessary at use of `tcolorbox`, and add new one which help me to design a table (`rotating`, `makecel` and `amssymb`)Well, it is not so fancy as with `tcolorbox` ... but it have different colors for odd and even rows (if you not liked, just put the same color in `\rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{gray!5}` :-) )

the first page:
[image]

and second page:
[image]

**Update:**
After while I see that the first row, used for caption is not colored properly. I suspect, that cause is not full compatibilita between packages `makecell` and `[table]{xcolor}` (whiich actualy activate `colortab`). This confirm @egre in his answer on my question `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246889/how-to-color-column-heads-determined-width-makecell` and give a solution  for this missmatch. You just replace rows in ma MWE

```
    \usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries}
...
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{gray!5}
\begin{longtable}{|R{\dimexpr 0.055\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
                   R{\dimexpr 0.521\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}||
                  *{10}{C{\dimexpr 0.04\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\large\textbf{Tabulka procesů}}  \\
```

width:

```
\newcommand{\thead}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \vrule height 1.2\ht\strutbox width 0pt\ignorespaces
  #1
  \unskip\vrule depth 1.2\dp\strutbox width 0pt
  \end{tabular}%
}
...
    \begin{longtable}{|R{\dimexpr 0.055\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
                   R{\dimexpr 0.521\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}||
                  *{10}{C{\dimexpr 0.04\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
    \hline
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\thead{Tabulka procesů}}  \\
    \hline
```

and the first row of table will look as should on the first place.  I replace first image with new one.

Comment: @Eliska Vlckova, see thread of my question mentioned in update. There is now new, better solution for coloring first row in your table.

Comment: Thanks, it's working great now. Only - do you think there's a way I could input `\caption{}` in the `multicolumn`? It's throwing `Misplaced \noalign.` exception, and I'm having trouble with finding any solution. I tried not using the `multicolumn` but then I'm missing the side lines and `\tabcolsep` can't be used there. @Zarko

Comment: No. Normally ``\caption`` following ``\bagin{longtable}, but this will screw-up your temporary table formatting. Solution is seems to be mimic of captions something like this ``\textbf{Table \thetable}: ...caption text ...`` Beside this you need to increment caption counter before and after this (not yet tested). Probbaly is good idea to ask new question here, maybe some one know better solution.

Comment: I must correct myself. You do not need manually increment table counter before and after mimic of table caption (tested). Even referencing works as should do.

Comment: Ok I'm using the `\thetable` solution for now, thanks. But I did ask another question for it here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247807/is-there-a-way-to-insert-caption-inside-a-multicolumn-on-top-of-a-longtable).

Comment: Meanwhile you got solution from David Carlise. I tested it in my answer. It works, but I'm not satisfied with coloring of the row with caption. The color is a bit shorter then row.