# How to color column heads determined width makecell

Tags: longtable, colortbl, makecell

In my answer to question [How do I repeat the first table row on every page using longtable inside of tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246763/how-do-i-repeat-the-first-table-row-on-every-page-using-longtable-inside-of-tcol/246843#246843)

I suggest to (between others) to use makecell package to define head of table and later I sow that the firs row is not colored as expected. It doesn't cover all row. Than I try to correct this with use of `cellcolor` construct as should be correctly done, when you use `multicolumn` (simplified MWE from mentioned question):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}%
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*{9}{b{\dimexpr 0.11\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}{\thead{head\\ 1}}}
    & \cellcolor{gray!30}{\thead{head\\ 2}}   \\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline\hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline\hline
\endhead
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I  \\
J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R  \\
S & T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z &    \\
    \hline\hline
\end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

and discover that that head in`multicolumn` doesn't has width of it and consequently head background color doesn't fill complete cell.

[image]

I Check `makecell` documentation, but doesn't find valuable information how to stretch actual head to cover entire cell. How to achieve that entire multicolum cell background will be colored?

**addendum:**
for this particular case the stretch `\thead` over whole `\multicolumn` can be done on the following way: instead of

```
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\thead{\hfill head\hfill\\ 1}}
```

the multi column cell should be defined as

```
\multicolumn{8}{|p{\dimexpr 0.88\linewidth-\tabcolsep}|}{\thead{\hfill head\hfill\\ 1}}
```

where `\dimexpr 0.88\linewidth-\tabcolsep` is the width of multi col cell. then the result is:

[image]

however, general solutions are given in answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the `\thead` in the `\multicolumn{|c|}` in a `\colorbox`, it works (somewhat redundantly…):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}%[table]
\usepackage{array, colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable, ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}%
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{9}{b{\dimexpr 0.11\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}%
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!30}\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{{\colorbox{gray!30}{\thead{head\\ 1}}}}
  & \thead{head\\ 2} \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline\hline
  \endfirsthead
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline\hline
  \endhead
  A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I \\
  J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R \\
  S & T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z & \\
  \hline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. But now I need to manually calculate width of columns which are spanned by ``multicolumn``. This can become annoying/problematic when the widths of column are not equal and/or determined with specifier with not a priory given width.

Comment: @Zarko: I changed the code to avoid those calculations: it's enough to put  to add a `\colorbox`. See my updated answer.

Comment: now I'm total confused. Why now this work and didn't in my first tray? I need detail examination of all my "experiments", to see where are differences. One another observation: you put ``array`` package twice in preamble, probably by mistake. I try to compile without it and also without ``ltablex`` package and obtain the same results as you show in your answer.

Comment: Now I observe differences: you add ``colortab`` in preamble and use ``colorbox`` instead ``cellcolor`` ... Good to know, thank you! I will change now my acceptances of answer.

Comment: Yes, `array` was loaded twice by mistake, I've corrected. I tested, and it doesn't seem to be required. I generally add it because it extends the syntax of the original `array` environment. As to `ltablex` it is there because I tested with a tabularx environment (it allows the latter to break across pages), but I get an error which I don't understand, about a spurious  `}`. You can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `makecell` is fully compatible with `colortbl`. However, you can easily emulate `\thead`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\thead}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \vrule height 1.2\ht\strutbox width 0pt\ignorespaces
  #1
  \unskip\vrule depth 1.2\dp\strutbox width 0pt
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{9}{b{\dimexpr 0.11\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}{\thead{head\\ 1}}}
    & \cellcolor{gray!30}{\thead{head\\ 2}}   \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\endhead
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I  \\
J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R  \\
S & T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z &    \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}\thead{head\\1}} & \thead{head\\2} \\
\hline
111 & 222 & 333 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\rowcolor` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: thank you for editing my question and for answer. You confirm my suspect that ``makecell`` and ``colortab`` are not full compatible. As I see, ``thead`` doesn't use complete width of "multi-column" cell.That means, that there is a chance that one day this will be fixed :-).  For particular case, mentioned in my question, where the first row is not multi-lined, is then better solution not use ``makecell`` and ``thead`` at all. Other wise, your solution is what I will use in future in similar cases.