# colortbl's \cellcolor not filling whole cell in combination with \makecell

Tags: tables, color, makecell

I want to color some cells of a table, some of which use `\makecell`. The problem I run into is that not the whole width of the `\makecell` cells is filled by the color.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
  Cell 1's text is very long \\
  \cellcolor{red} \makecell{Cell\\2}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The desired behavior is of course to have the whole cell filled, so how can I do that?

Edit:
I'm using `\makecell` to get a cell consisting of multiple lines in my original problem, so I've updated the MWE to do that as well. If there's any other method of doing that without using `makecell` I'm willing to do so as well.

Comment: You might be interested in the following question, where the problem of coloring `makecell`s was already discussed: [How to color column heads determined width makecell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246889/134144) Using a combination of `\cellcolor` and `\colorbox` should work for your case as well.

Comment: I tried placing a `\colorbox` inside my `\makecell` but that didn't look any different.

Comment: Placing the `\colorbox` command around the `\makecell` command will yield a completely colored cell: `\cellcolor{red} \colorbox{red}{\makecell{Cell 2}}`

Comment: It works! I thought I had tried that one earlier...
Could you add your last comment as anwser so I can mark it as solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it isn't a duplicate of the mentioned link: this one does *not* have fixed width columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is known that `makecell`  has problems with  coloured tables. Here are two work-arounds:

- one plays with `\rowcolor` and its overhang optional arguments, the other replaces `makecell` with `tabStackengine`. It is worth noting that, as the column has the `l` specifier, the content of the `\makecell` command can be centred globally in the cell, playing with the placement parameters, but the two rows can't be centred w.r.t. each other.
- the other solution uses package `tabstackengine`, which doesn't have the same problems with colouring cells, and `\multicolumn`  to obtain a centred content.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{tabstackengine}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
  Cell 1's text is very long \\
  \rowcolor{red}[\tabcolsep][47pt]\makecell[r]{Cell 2\\ Text} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor{yellow}}c|}{\tabularCenterstack{c}{Cell 3\\ Text}}
  \end{tabular}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\Block` which provides the functionnalities of `\makecell` (and others). Concerning colors, you have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|l|}
  Cell 1's text is very long \\
  \Block[fill=red]{}{Cell\\2}
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]