# Is there a way to insert \caption{} inside a multicolumn on top of a longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable, multicolumn

I have a coloured table and I'd like it to be sort of uniform and have the `\caption` inside the coloured space serving as a title as well.
I can insert the table number with `\thetable` but then I'd have to manually add it to the `\listoftables` for every table so I'm looking for a better solution. Thanks for any advice.

Here's my simplified code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}b}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{gray!5}

\begin{longtable}{|R{\dimexpr 0.08\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
                   R{\dimexpr 0.52\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}||
                  C{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
                  C{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large\textbf{Table \thetable : Tabulka procesů }} \T \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
A & B & C & D\\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
A & B & C & D\\  \\
\hline\hline
\endhead
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need those vertical rules? I'm thinking in particular to the double vertical rule that doubly serves no purpose (vertical rules serve no purpose in tables in general).

Comment: @egreg Maybe this table doesn't need it, but in the past I've had problems with this - the text in a row had too much space on the bottom and not enough on top. Sometimes I had to go for the `\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}` overkill to compensate - and I still don't know why that happens... Anyway that's beside the point - would you know how to fix the `\caption`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

longtable's `\caption` is already a `\multicolumn{4}{c}` (in this case) you just want to redefine it to be `{|c|}` so

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}b}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{gray!5}
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \LT@mcol\LT@cols{|c|}{#1{#2: }#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{longtable}{|R{0.08\dimexpr(\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth-\doublerulesep-.4pt)}|
                   R{ .52\dimexpr(\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth-\doublerulesep-.4pt)}||
                  C{.2\dimexpr  (\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth-\doublerulesep-.4pt)}|
                  C{.2\dimexpr  (\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth-\doublerulesep-.4pt)}|}

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\caption{Tabulka procesů}\\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
A & B & C & D\\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
A & B & C & D\\  \\
\hline\hline
\endhead
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks - is there a way to also specify that the caption should be bold and larger? I'm having trouble adding it there...

Comment: `{#1{#2: }#3}`  to `{#1{\large\bfseries#2: }\large\bfseries#3}`

Comment: Is there a manual for these definitions?

Comment: @EliskaVlckova not really, I wasn't expecting people to poke there, but it's my code so it's probably OK if I suggest a redefinition:-)

Comment: @DaidCarlisle I was just curious :-) - this seems pretty handy to know, but I haven't really came across any study materials that would explain these things.

Comment: @EliskaVlckova the caption package offers a more sane and documented way to customise caption styling for normal and longtable captions, but it can't (I think) change the `c` to `|c|` as you requested so to do that need to open up longtable internals and redefine LT@makecaption, and having done that you need to directly address the styling at the same place rather than attempt to use the caption package definitions.

Comment: I'd hate to bother you, but do you think you could modify the code for `\longtable` to acommodate `\caption{}` inside of a `\tabular` or `\tabularx` as well? Thanks, I can't crack it :D, it's always stuck in the first cell for some reason. I would use `\longtable`, but that only works if it's as wide as the text is, otherwise the table lines are too long... @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @EliskaVlckova a caption inside tabular inside longtable? easiest way is probably to use \newbox\mybox ...  \sbox\mybox{\begin{tabular}...   before tha longtable then \usebox\mybox where you want the tabular

Comment: no no, just a `\caption` inside a `\tabular`

Comment: @EliskaVlckova why?  but you can use `capt-of` package and use `\captionof{table}{my caption here...}` more or less anywhere, but captions normally go above not in the tabular.